# sub navigation div keeps hiding

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, mouseout

I have a nasty navigation problem but can't seem to get it to work. When hovering over the `<li>` items in the mainnav div, according subnavigation shows.
But it won't stay in active class state when hovering over them. When a mainnav-li is selected, the subnav should stay. When moving off the subnav, the initial subnav should reappear.

Please note we load an active subnav after the document.ready function (defined in another PHP include).

Any help is highly appreciated here. I got lost :-)

All the main li-navigation items go here:

```
<div id="navigation-main">
    <div id="mainnav"> 
    <div class="navigation-items">
        <ul> 
        <li id="mainnav1" class="active"><a href="#" id="header">Button 1</a></li> 
        <li id="mainnav2"><a href="#">Button 2</a></li> 
        <li id="mainnav3"><a href="#">Button 3</a></li> 
        <li id="mainnav4"><a href="#">Button 4</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

The Subdivs are:

```
<div id="navigation-sub1" class="navigation-sub">navigation-sub 1  active</div> 
<div id="navigation-sub2" class="navigation-sub">navigation-sub 2 active</div> 
<div id="navigation-sub3" class="navigation-sub">navigation-sub 3 active</div> 
<div id="navigation-sub4" class="navigation-sub">navigation-sub 4 active</div>
```

Here's my code so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var activeId = $(".active").attr("id").replace("mainnav",""); 
    $("#navigation-sub" + activeId).show();

    $("#mainnav a").hover(function() { 
        //reset 
        $(".navigation-sub").hide(); 
        $("#mainnav .active").removeClass("active"); 

        //act 
        $(this).addClass("active") 
        var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("mainnav",""); 
        $("#navigation-sub" + id).show();

    }); 

    $("#mainnav").mouseout(function() {
        $(".navigation-sub").hide(); 
        $("#navigation-sub" + activeId).show();
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Could you provide better HTML? It's a little hard to see where the elements are in relation to one another in your example.

Comment: Thanks Joey,
I changed the HTML code in the post. Also, here's an online example:

http://www.digiport.nl/tst/testnav.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the `.navigation-sub` into the `mainnav` in order to hide it on mouseleave of the `mainnav`. Also, you were using mouseout, when i think you meant mouseleave:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3YpU/5/

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: You rock Joey! Sometimes you just need someone else to have a look at it :)

Comment: Glad i could provide an answer :)